# CSS hover effect does not work and I find it lost

Tags: html, css

Below code  doesn't work in any other browser.I'd like to use a hover effect to change the property of `popup` ,but it doesn't work.And I can't find this style in google chrome developer tools.

```
.footer-about-yqsl ul.footer-social .social-wechat:hover .social-wechat .popup{
    display:block !important;
}

.footer-about-yqsl ul.footer-social .social-app .popup{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 26px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 144px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

And html code like this:

```
<div class="footer-about-yqsl">
    <ul class="footer-social">
        <li class="social-wechat social-app">
            <a class="ga-data" href="https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/yezse2ypY0RNXB9KdPX-3w" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-ga-category="pc-footer"  data-ga-label="social-wechat">
                <img src="http://www.isuzi.top/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/ead4fc6850bc8dd360e91db867446a68.png" alt="wechat" />
            </a>
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="er-code">
                    <img class="dps" src="http://www.isuzi.top/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/4413ccaad4601bce612a1ca9bcfefb4f.png" data-dps-src="http://www.isuzi.top/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/4413ccaad4601bce612a1ca9bcfefb4f.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know it's mayby a dumb question to ask,but I tried to use css, javascript or jquery, all in vain.

See web screen shot :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOz1x.png

I can't find the css sentence in the Styles of Google Chrome.

I just noticed this today.

Any ideas??Thank you.

Comment: You could just give the div with the class `popup` another class. Or try and just target `.popup` in your css with your desired changes. Check the tools again and see what your inspecter is chucking out..

Comment: @mrpbennett  It succeeded when I only targeted `.popup`,but  when I used `hover` it failed.And in google chrome ,I find the cursor sometims change to the not-allowed style,but I just set `cursor :pointer`

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with your first selector, this for example is working:

```
.footer-about-yqsl ul.footer-social .social-wechat:hover .popup
{
    display:block!important; 
}

.footer-about-yqsl ul.footer-social .social-app .popup{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 26px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 144px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I get it.Actually，I am very unfamiliar with selectors, so I made a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

This selector...

```
.footer-about-yqsl ul.footer-social .social-wechat:hover .social-wechat .popup
```

...contains `.social-wechat` *twice*, so there would have to be a `.social-wechat` element *inside*  another - hovered - `.social-wechat` element for it to apply, which doesn't exist in your HTML code. You might want to try this selector instead:

```
.footer-about-yqsl ul.footer-social .social-wechat:hover .popup
```

Comment: Yes，It works.It's completely caused by my carelessness,perhaps I need to spend more time studying web developing and study fast.